# IDEA's Spring Initializr + Kotlin wizard (2019.1 update) for new project fails with JDK version error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to create a new IntelliJ IDEA project (v 2019.1) with Spring Boot + Kotlin language. I chose:
- Kotlin 1.2 as SDK (First/default New Project dialog)
- Kotlin as Language (Second screen)
- Java 8 as the target language version. (Second screen - I don't see Kotlin as an available option)
Generation of the starter stops with an error that says "Selected Java version 8 is not supported by SDK (maximum 1.2)".

Looks like a selection options filter issue. What can I change to get this going?

Comment: What JDKs did you configure in Project Structure | SDKs? Try to remove them all and add only one for Java 8.